# IllegalStateException with VertX only when attaching a file

Tags: java, vert.x

Im building a proxy with Java VertX. This code works fine when there are not attached files:

```
this.router = Router.router(vertx);

this.bodyHandler = BodyHandler.create();
this.router.route().handler(this.bodyHandler);

this.corsHandler = CorsHandler.create("*");
this.corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
this.corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
this.corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
this.corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
this.corsHandler.allowedHeader("Content-Type");
this.corsHandler.allowedHeader("Authorization");
this.corsHandler.allowedHeader("X-User");
this.corsHandler.allowedHeader("X-Service-Id");
this.router.route().handler(this.corsHandler);

router.route().handler(routingContext -> {

    HttpServerResponse res = routingContext.response();

    HttpClient httpClient = this.vertx.createHttpClient(new HttpClientOptions());

    HttpClientRequest c_req = httpClient.request(
            routingContext.request().method(), 
            serviceParams.getServicePort(),
            serviceParams.getServiceAddress(),
            serviceParams.getPrefix() + routingContext.request().uri(),
            c_res -> 
    {
        // Set response handlers...
    });

    c_req.headers().setAll(routingContext.request().headers());

    c_req.setChunked(true); // I have tested both values: true and false

    c_req.exceptionHandler(ex -> {
        // Here is fired the exception 2 minutes later
    });

    c_req.end(routingContext.getBody());
}
```

When I attach a file, A java.lang.IllegalStateException is fired 2 minutes later. The destination HTTP server doesnt register any incoming request. I dont know why.

```
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response is closed
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.checkValid(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:548)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.putHeader(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:153)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.putHeader(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:53)
    at lotto.proxy.ProxyVerticle.returnResponse(ProxyVerticle.java:242)
    at lotto.proxy.ProxyVerticle.returnFail(ProxyVerticle.java:235)
    at lotto.proxy.ProxyVerticle.lambda$null$2(ProxyVerticle.java:171)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryFail(FutureImpl.java:165)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.fail(FutureImpl.java:97)
    at lotto.proxy.impl.Dispatcher.lambda$null$5(Dispatcher.java:227)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestBase.handleException(HttpClientRequestBase.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestImpl.handleException(HttpClientRequestImpl.java:50)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection.handleClosed(Http1xClientConnection.java:730)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:337)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:195)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelInactive(VertxHandler.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientHandler.channelInactive(Http1xClientHandler.java:91)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:420)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:377)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:282)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1354)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:917)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

These are the request headers:

- Content-Type:    multipart/form-data;
  boundary=--------------------------223339033491069994639481
- X-Service-Id:    wallets-service
- Authorization:   sboj5qre29cq67famfhmk0hbqnvq7c63alrne2aad6hftj7q9nmu
- cache-control:   no-cache
- Postman-Token:   3ae4d47c-53ca-46bc-9959-1d4a4c9c1b60
- User-Agent:  PostmanRuntime/7.1.5 Accept:    */* Host:   localhost:8100
- accept-encoding: gzip, deflate content-length:   2664
- Connection:  keep-alive

I think all I have given all details. Thank you in advance!

**Update**: Thanks to @alexey-soshin, answering him I provide extra information:

- Version of Vertx: 3.5.2, but with Vertx version 3.2.0 it works!!!
- routingContext.getBody() is empty (not null).
- I'm sure it's the Vertx layer because without it, the destination HTTP server catchs the request and everything works fine.
- File attachment:

[image: File attachement with Postman]

Comment: Could you please post how do you try to upload the file? My guess is that you're not actually sending it, then the server breaks the connection upon timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your interest @alexey-soshin. I've updated the post.

Comment: Not sure, why it works with Vert.x 3.2.0, but in newer versions you'll get uploaded files as `FileUpload` objects. Did you check them?

Comment: Yes, a folder named 'file-uploads' is created. But I don't know how I can resend the entire request body.

With old versions, body is intact, but with new versions is empty.